# Wordpress theme - remove unused css

Tags: javascript, wordpress, gulp

I have a wordpress theme and I want to remove unused css.
So I try to use Gulp+uncss

Theme Folder structure

```
CSS/main.css
-gulpfile.js
```

Wordpress site url
localhot/wpsite

And I have gulpfile.js

```
//Include Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

//Include plugins
    var uncss = require('gulp-uncss');
    var rename = require('gulp-rename');

    //Uncss task
    gulp.task('uncss', function() {

        gulp.src('css/main.css')  
            .pipe(uncss({        
                html: [  'http://localhot/wpsite/','http://localhot/wpsite/about' ]  
            }))      

        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.clean'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));

    });
```

But I can`t get new clean css file

Comment: did you generated site map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you see the above(your code) gulpfile.js

If you have just a few pages, like 20 or less, you can just go ahead and copy and paste the URL’s if not then you will need a plugin for this. There’s a plugin that is designed for Grunt but also works fine with Gulp. You can find it [**here**](https://github.com/phoenixMag00/JSON-Sitemap-Generator-for-Grunt-UnCSS-with-WordPress) with easy-to-follow instructions on how to use it.

After you activate it, go to:

http://yourdomain.com?show_sitemap

You’ll see some code, just Select all and copy then paste it in the gulpfile.js inside the uncss function after “html:”

After you copy the array, save the file. Then, in the command-line, type:

```
gulp uncss
```

So now, if you look at your CSS folder or wherever you chose for your destination path, you will see a new lean CSS with the suffix ‘.clean’ that should look something like this:

[image]

Check once the below link. It will clearly describes, How to Remove Unused CSS in WordPress Using Gulp from the gulp installation

[Remove Unused CSS](http://uplifted.net/programming/remove-unused-css-wordpress-using-gulp/)